# How can I get year from the date field

Tags: postgresql

How can I get year from the date field, If I have a date field `product_date`, it has 1000 entries per year I want to take a YEAR wise record. product_date = 2013/01/01 like i want search 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM product_date ) FROM tbl_product;
```

sort your table according to `YEAR`

```
 with cte as(
 SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM product_date) as myYear FROM tbl_product order by myYear
 )
 select product_date,* from tbl_product where  extract(year from product_date) in (select myYear    
 from cte)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what "year wise record" should mean because you failed to supply some sample data, but to get the year from a date column, you can use the `extract()` function:

```
select *
from some_table
where extract(year from product_date) = 2013;
```

For details about the `extract` function, please  see the manual: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

The above however will not make use of an index on the `product_date` column. So if performance is really important you have two options:

- create an index on `extract(year from product_date)`
- use a between clause:

  ```
  select *
  from some_table
  where product_date between date '2013-01-01' and date '2013-12-31';
  ```